Modus AssemblyScript SDK Installation issue
I'm currently facing an issue installing the Modus AssemblyScript SDK, and I could use some assistance. I have a stable internet connection, but when I attempt to install the SDK with the command:
modus sdk install assemblyscript 0.13.4
I get the following error message:
Modus CLI v0.13.7
✖ Failed to download Modus AssemblyScript SDK v0.13.4
    Error: No internet connection. You must be online to install a Modus SDK.

I tried to troubleshoot this by manually downloading the source code from GitHub. I extracted the files into the appropriate folder and made sure to follow all relevant steps (including running npm install where applicable). However, I’m still getting the same issue. Other parts of the setup process worked fine, so it seems specific to this SDK installation.
Could anyone suggest a solution or any additional steps I might be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
Also check this , i have installed it manually and then also the issue remain
see this
▗▖  ▗▖ ▗▄▖ ▗▄▄▄ ▗▖ ▗▖ ▗▄▄▖
▐▛▚▞▜▌▐▌ ▐▌▐▌  █▐▌ ▐▌▐▌   
▐▌  ▐▌▐▌ ▐▌▐▌  █▐▌ ▐▌ ▝▀▚▖
▐▌  ▐▌▝▚▄▞▘▐▙▄▄▀▝▚▄▞▘▗▄▄▞▘

Modus CLI v0.13.7

Create a new Modus app

✔ Select a SDK AssemblyScript
✔ Pick a name for your app: ops-blueprint
✔ Continue? yes

 ERROR : Could not find an installed Modus AssemblyScript SDK.


This issue has been fixed with Modus CLI 0.13.8.  Please reinstall and try again.  Thanks.
